# GDB macro maintain counter of objects

Tags: python, gdb

I need to maintain counter of each type of object seen while iterating over list of objects in gdb script and print it at last.

since gdb doesn't support dictionaries (key, value pair)

For example, in python,

```
    counts = {}
    //get opcode
    if not opcode in counts:
           counts[opcode] = 1
    else:
          counts[opcode] += 1
```

how can i do it in a gdb macro?

Answer (score 0):

It depends somewhat on what `opcode` is.

The name suggests that you're looking at an interpreter or something like that.  If so, and if the possible range of values is small, then you can do it quite easily just using the gdb CLI; in fact, I've done exactly this before.

Basically you would just allocate an array and use the opcode as an index into it.  Something like:

```
(gdb) set var counts = (int *) malloc (MAX * sizeof (int))
(gdb) call memset (counts, 0, MAX * sizeof (int))
(gdb) break somewhere
(gdb) commands
    >   silent
    >   set var counts[opcode] = counts[opcode] + 1
    >   cont
    > end
```

This approach will work ok for basic things.  It has a hidden issue, which is that the `cont` in the breakpoint commands will interfere with a `next` entered at the command line.  That is, if you are `next`ing through the code, and the breakpoint is hit, the `next` will act like you typed `cont` instead.  This is fixable using the Python API.

If `opcode` has a bigger range, then you have a couple of choices.  One choice would be to find a way to compress the large range to a smaller and use the above.  Another choice would be to simply script gdb in Python, and use Python's associative arrays instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can script GDB with Python, nowadays. You can use Python dictionaries to store object counts easily. As a most basic example:

```
user@host $ gdb ./a.out
[...]
$ break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000b60
$ commands
> python
 >t = {}
 >>$ break *main+0x2a
Breakpoint 3 at 0x100000b86
$ commands
>python
 >t[0] = 1
 >>gdb$ run

[...]

Breakpoint 3, 0x0000000100000b86 in main ()
$ python
> print(t)
>{0: 1}
```

See the [manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html#Python-API) for a complete list of APIs given.